# Missing Something Sending Prop In Link In React

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

**What I'm Attempting To Do:**

Have a list created from an API that lists several teams, each linked to a new team page via their team ID. Example:

Homepage:   Localhost:3000/

Lists several options:

```
Search By Team
Search By Player
```

click on Search By Team, listing each team   Localhost:3000/teams

```
Gladiators
Maniacs
```

Click on Maniacs   localhost:3000/Maniacs

So far when I click on each team, it takes me to the 404 page.

**What I Have Now:**

App.js

```
        <Route path="/teams" component={Teams} exact></Route> 
        <Route exact path='/:teamName' component={EachTeam} />
```

Standings.js

```
import Atlantic from "../components/divisions/Atlantic"
function Standings() {
return (
    <div className="teams-container">
        <Atlantic />
    </div>
)
}
   export default NHLStandings
```

Altantic.js

```
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
function Atlantic() {
const [teams, setTeams] = useState(null);
useEffect(() => {
    getData();

async function getData() {
    const response = await fetch("RANDOM_API);
    const data = await response.json();
    setTeams(data) ;
    }
}, []);


return (
    <div className="container">
        {teams && (
            <div className="container">
                <h2>Atlantic Division</h2>
            {teams['teams'].map((team, index) => (
                (team.division.name === "Atlantic" && (
                    <Link 
                        to={`/${team.teamName}`} 
                        teamName={team.teamName}
                        key={index} 
                        className="team-container"
                    >
                        <h2>{team.name}</h2>
                    </Link>
                ))
            ))}
        </div>
    )}
    </div>
)
}
```

export default Atlantic

EachTeam.js

```
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import { useState, useEffect, useSelector } from 'react';

function EachTeam(props) {


 return (
    <div className="container">
        <h1>{props.teamName}</h1>
    </div>
)
}
export default EachTeam
```

Apologies for the length, I did not want to omit anything. Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: If i'm not mistaken - you should not use exact in your second Route

Comment: This did not help, unfortunately. The URL still updates dynamically and no information is passed in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`teamName` isn't a valid prop on either the `Link` component or the `Route` component. The extraneous props are ignored. I suspect you are navigating correctly and just seeing `props.teamName` as undefined.

```
{teams['teams'].map((team, index) => (
  (team.division.name === "Atlantic" && (
    <Link 
      to={`/${team.teamName}`} 
      teamName={team.teamName} // <-- ignored, not a Link prop
      key={index} 
      className="team-container"
    >
      <h2>{team.name}</h2>
    </Link>
  ))
))}
```

To resolve you can access the route match params to get the `teamName`. In function components use the [useParams](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Hooks/useparams) React hook.

Given:

```
<Route exact path='/:teamName' component={EachTeam} />
```

EachTeam

```
import { useParams } from 'react-router-dom';

function EachTeam(props) {
  const { teamname } = useParams();

  return (
    <div className="container">
      <h1>{teamName}</h1>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: That did it! Thank you, I really appreciate the help.